# Getting 'Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument' while converting mail to pdf using outlook vba

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook, arguments, export-to-pdf

The outlook VBA, Check for emails sent to a specific folder in Outlook called "Receipts With Tax."
When an email is moved to the "Receipts With Tax" folder, Convert the email to a PDF format.
Once the PDF is generated and saved, the script move the email from the "Receipts With Tax" folder to the "Receipts" folder in Outlook.

But it seem to be working on one machine, getting error on second machine.

**Error A --** first error related to "a file error has occur" is due to the fact that the file was opened previously and the macro was stopped prematurely. this will resolve.
This error will gone as soon as you restart the windows.
**But I need to make sure that following code can handle this error**

**Error B --** as I restart, this Error occurs:
"invalid procedure call or argument - error 5"

I have point out the errors in the following Subroutine `SaveAsPDFfile()`:

```
'wTaxReceipts -> PDF -> Receipts
Const Receipts_With_Tax As String = "Receipts With Tax"
Const Receipts As String = "Receipts"
Const pdfPath As String = "C:\Users\MBA\Desktop\PDFs\"

Public WithEvents Receipts_With_Tax_FOLDERS As Outlook.Folders

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim MyNS As NameSpace
    Set MyNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Receipts_With_Tax_FOLDERS = MyNS.Folders(1).Folders
End Sub

Private Sub Receipts_With_Tax_FOLDERS_FolderChange(ByVal Folder As Outlook.Folder)

    If Folder.name = Receipts_With_Tax Then
        Dim toPDF As Object
        Set toPDF = Folder.Items.GetFirst
        If toPDF Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        sTaxReceipts_2_Receipts toPDF
    End If
    
End Sub
Sub sTaxReceipts_2_Receipts(iFirst As Outlook.mailItem)

    Dim MyNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolderReceipts As Outlook.Folder
    Dim MyPath As String

    Set MyNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolderReceipts = MyNS.Folders(1).Folders(Receipts)

    MyPath = pdfPath & iFirst.SenderEmailAddress & " " & Format(iFirst.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmmss") & ".pdf"
    
    SaveAsPDFfile iFirst, MyPath
    
    iFirst.Move olFolderReceipts

    Set olFolderReceipts = Nothing
    Set MyNS = Nothing

End Sub
Sub SaveAsPDFfile(objItem As Outlook.mailItem, MyPath As String)

    Dim wrdApp As Object
    Dim wrdDoc As Object
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strCurrentFile As String
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set tmpFileName = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)

    strName$ = "www_howto-outlook_com"
    tmpFileName = tmpFileName & "\" & strName & ".mht"
    objItem.SaveAs tmpFileName, olMHTML ' Error A -- "a file error has occur"


    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    'wrdApp.Visible = False
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=tmpFileName, Visible:=False)
        
    'Clean PDF-File Name
'    strFileName = objItem.subject
'    Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
'    oRegEx.Global = True
'    oRegEx.Pattern = "[\/:*?""<>|]"
'    strFileName = Trim(oRegEx.Replace(strFileName, ""))

    'MyPath & strFileName
    strCurrentFile = MyPath
    
        'Save as pdf
    'wrdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strCurrentFile, _
        ExportFormat:=17, OptimizeFor:=0, Range:=0, From:=0, To:=0, _
        item:=0, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=0, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
        UseISO19005_1:=False
        
        'Error B -- "invalid procedure call or argument"
        wrdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        strCurrentFile, ExportFormat:= _
        wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, _
        item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False


    
    ' close the document and Word
    wrdDoc.Close
    wrdApp.Quit

    'Cleanup
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set tmpFileName = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set WshShell = Nothing
    Set oRegEx = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code under the debugger attached? Which line of code exactly throws the error?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have menstioned error lines in the code, please check

Comment: Have you tried using the `WordEditor` property instead of opening a separate file and creating a new Word `Application` instance?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook folders may contain different item types - mail, appointment, document, post and etc. So, the following code get the first item from the `Items` collection:

```
Set toPDF = Folder.Items.GetFirst
If toPDF Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
sTaxReceipts_2_Receipts toPDF
```

And pass to a method which expects an instance of the `MailItem` class to be passed:

```
Sub sTaxReceipts_2_Receipts(iFirst As Outlook.mailItem)
```

So, I'd suggest checking the item type or the `MessageClass` (or just `Class`) property before calling the method.

Be aware, instead of creating new Word `Application` instance you may try using the [Inspector.WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property which returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The returned Word `Document` object provides access to most of the Word object model.